# Вывод данных из двух таблиц базы данных при поиске

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli, поиск

Пишу скрипт для поиска. Имеется база данных, которая содержит две таблицы. При поиске нужно чтобы происходил поиск из двух таблиц базы данных. Не совсем понимаю, как реализовать поиск из двух таблиц, чтобы при этом производился предикат LIKE. Прощу помощи.

```
     function search ($query) 
{ 

   mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
   $servername = "localhost";
   $username = "root";
   $password = "";
   $dbname = "shelter";   
   $connect = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

   mysqli_query($connect, 'SET NAMES utf8');


    $query = trim($query); 
    $query = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $query);
    $query = htmlspecialchars($query);

    if (!empty($query)) 
    { 
        if (strlen($query) < 3) {
            $text = '<p>Слишком короткий поисковый запрос.</p>';
        } else if (strlen($query) > 128) {
            $text = '<p>Слишком длинный поисковый запрос.</p>';
        } else { 

             // тут должен происходить поиск из ДВУХ таблиц :(
            $q = "SELECT `name`, `imagePath`
                  FROM `cats-find-home` WHERE `name` LIKE '%$query%'";

            $result = mysqli_query($connect, $q);

            if (mysqli_affected_rows($connect) > 0) { 
                $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result); 

                do {
                  $name = $row['name'];
                  $iamgePath = $row['imagePath'];

                  echo '<div class="item__catalog">';
   
                  echo '<a href="#"><img src="' . $iamgePath .'">';
                  echo '<h1>'. $name .'</h1></a>';
                  break;
                } while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)); 
            } else {
                $text = '<p>По вашему запросу ничего не найдено.</p>';
            }
        } 
    } else {
        $text = '<p>Задан пустой поисковый запрос.</p>';
    } 
}  

   ?>
      
<?php 
if (!empty($_POST['query'])) { 
    $search_result = search($_POST['query']); 
    echo $search_result; 
}
?>
```

Comment: `union` в помощь. `select x from y where z like ':query' UNION select a from b where c LIKE ':query'`

Comment: Спасибо, но не совсем понимаю синтаксис, sql подзабыл

Comment: Спасибо большое. Всё работает :)